# how to remove ssh warning in shell script

Tags: shell-script, ssh

I'm trying to execute a shell script that connects to other machine by ssh and execute a sql command. It works but always shows me warning like:

```
"stty: tcgetattr: Not a typewriter"
```

My shell script is like these:

```
... ssh -q -T -T $connection <<ENDSSH 
sqlplus -s "user/pass@con" <<EOF
set heading off
select * from ...
EOF
ENDSSH
```

How could I remove it?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Run the script with TTY:

```
... ssh -q -tt $connection <<ENDSSH 
sqlplus -s "user/pass@con" <<EOF
set heading off
select * from ...
EOF
ENDSSH
```

(note the `-T` replaced with `-tt`)

Comment: It works but says me other warning message: tcgetattr: Inappropriate ioctl for device